# How to compared the captured image with 2 data science models and get the prediction

Tags: javascript, html, flask, model, data-science

Hi i'm building a Anime recommendation system based on user emotion for my project. I created the webpage for webcam stream it can capture the image and save it in localstorage of the web browser. Also i have two models i trained. First one is the emotion_detection_model_50epochs.h5(89% accuracy) and second one is gender_model_50epochs.h5(78% accuracy). This is the code use for create the camera section and capture the image in web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <button id="snap">Take Photo</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let video = document.querySelector('#video');

if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(stream =>{
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    });
}

document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // convert canvas image to data URL
    localStorage.setItem('capturedImage', dataURL); // store data URL in local storage
});
```

I need to compare the captured image with 2 models and shown the prediction what is the user emotion type and what is the gender of user in the webpage. How i can do this using flask?